# Error when trying to call a function that will add data to vector

Tags: c++, class, vector

I get an error that I believe is caused by the function I wrote to store data from a file in a vector in my class called store in store.cpp.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "store.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    store data;
    ifstream inFile ("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Albums.csv");
    string line;
    string item;
    int num;
    int itemnum;
    int linenum = 0;
    while (getline (inFile, line))
    {
        linenum++;
        cout << endl << "Line #" << linenum << ":" << endl;
        istringstream linestream(line);
        itemnum = 0;
        num = 0;
        while (getline (linestream, item, ','))
        {
            itemnum++;
            if (itemnum == 2 || itemnum == 3 || itemnum == 4 || itemnum == 6)
            {
                num++;
                data.addtovect(linenum, num, item);
            }
            cout << "Item #" << itemnum << ": " << item << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Store.h

```
#ifndef STORE_H
#define STORE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class store
{
    public:
        store();
        void addtovect(int, int, string);
        void print();

    private:

        vector< vector<string> > fullline();
};

#endif
```

Store.cpp

```
#include "store.h"

store::store()
{

}
void store::addtovect(int a, int b, string c)
{
    fullline[a][b].push_back(c);
}
void store::print()
{

}
```

The error is:

> C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\C++ projects\csc125\lab4\store.cpp|9|error: invalid types '<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]' for array subscript|.

I tried looking for a way to fix it, but I didn't really come any closer to figuring it out. Some of the things I saw said that the error was caused by the vector being confused with a function, but I have no idea how I could fix it.

Comment: `|` isn't logical OR; its *bitwise*. try `||`

Comment: Woops, thanks, fixed that part, but still got the error. I actually only used = instead of == earlier too, surprised i didn't catch that mistake too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your header file you define fullline as a function that returns a vector containing vectors containing strings:

```
vector< vector<string> > fullline();
```

Remove the parentheses and it will instead be a vector containing vectors containing strings.

```
vector< vector<string> > fullline;
```

*Edit:*
When you try to add the string to your `fullline` vectors, you will have some issues:
1) The inner vector is not created, you will at some point have to `push_back` a vector into the first vector.
2) You are trying to push your string into a string:

```
fullline[a][b].push_back(c);

fullline < This is your first vector.
fullline[a] < Here you get the secondary vector.
fullline[a][b] < Here you get the object within the second vector (a string).
fullline[a][b].push_back(c) < Here you try to push back c into the string.
```

Comment: i tried that and this time it said "error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string<char>::push_back(std::string&)'|"

Comment: Thats cause you are running push_back on a string, not vector, let me update answer r/q. :)

Comment: Okay, so i see what i was doing wrong, but i'm honestly pretty confused about how i'm going to fix it. What i'm trying to do is take information from a list that has information about different albums, like the name and the band, so i was trying to use [b] for that information, and the [a] to kinda separate it all, so i only want the fullline[a] to get pushed back?

Comment: You will have to create a vector first, to actually access via `fullline[a]`, but then, yes, you fetch `fullline[a]` and `push_back` the string to that vector. (cause `fullline[a]` is the   `vector<string>` object).

Comment: so i created a new vector called v, then did v.push_back(a), and then did fullline.push_back(v), i tried to get it to just print the values it stored with a simple loop, but it tells me "error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << ((store*)this)->store::fullline.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >(((std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::size_type)i))'|      "I'm at my wit's end with this, i'm just not understanding it.

Comment: Show how you print it (comment will do).

Comment: v.push_back(a);
    fullline.push_back(v);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        cout << fullline[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }

Comment: `fullline[i]` is a vector, you need to loop both! :) And I would recommend using a for-loop in the example, cause `while(1)` is a loop that will never end :)

Comment: Something like: `for(unsigned int i=0;i<fullline.size();i++) {  for(unsigned int j=0;j<fullline[i].size();j++) { std::cout << fullline[i][j] << std::endl; } }`

Comment: okay sweet, the printing works, now to figure out the other push_back. the for loops also seem to go on forever, could that be because the vector size would be constantly increasing?

Comment: That depends on if you are keep on pushing to the array! If my answer gave you enough information to solve the initial question, please feel free to mark it as correct. :)

Comment: Ah, okay, i can fix that then. I'm still having issues pushing into the [b] of fullline[a][b], i tried fulline[a].push_back(c), but that results in a crash

Comment: Double check so that the index `a` exists in the vector.

Comment: it should be, because that should reference the first value from the fullline.push_back(v) since a = 1 at that point

Comment: If you have only pushed one vector to the `fullline` vector, there will be no index 1, vectors (and most stuff in programming) start at index 0. So if `a == 1` there will be an out of bounds error, it should be 0.

Comment: Wow, i can't believe i missed that too, i'm too tired for this apparently. Alright, all the data goes in the right place, and it starts to print, but it looks like at some point i get garbage numbers, will the push_back push a null entry too? because if not, that might be the issue, but i'm not sure

Comment: er no, i think its not stopping at the bottom of the file

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is

```
     vector< vector<string> > fullline
```

`fullline` is a vector, `fullline[a]` is a vector, but `fullline[a][b]` is a string.

`string` is basically vector<char>, so it also has the `push_back` method, but you can only `push_back` a char to string.